# Searching for an element within lists of lists

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list with elements of the following form:

```
[['37a1', 1], 153, 160, [[13, 2], [53, -1], [67, 2], [127, -1], [443, -1], [547, 2], [599, -1]]]
[['57a1', 1], 155, 157, [[5, 2], [11, -1]]]
[['198a1', 1], 156, 156, []]
[['551c1', 1], 155, 158, [[5, 5], [43, -1], [149, -1]]]
```

How may I search for elements in the list such that `[anything,-1]` is part of my element? In this case, the first two and last elements should return as my answer.

I know how to pull out just one element in the list that matches `['37a1',1]` for instance:

```
matches = [x for x in regs if ['37a1', 1] in x]; matches
```

I'm guessing based on this that I should be doing something very similar to the above, but replacing `['37a1', 1]` with someway of indicating 'anything'. As another example, I want to be able to search `[anything,5]` within my element and return the last element in this list as my output.

Comment: `In this case, the first two elements should return as my answer` is unclear to me. Do you have 4 lists in your example or just a single list?

Comment: It is a single list. Each line is one element.

Comment: @HaikalYeo: but your sublists are nested; `[67, 2] in x` would never match, for example because that sublist is inside *another* sublist.

Comment: Why should the first two be returned but not the fourth?

Comment: @Trengot you are right. I added the fourth one later for the [anything,5] example. I will amend. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you wanted to test for sublists in the *last element* of each list, not the first 3 elements.

You'll need to test against each element in each nested list; using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) would make that a little more efficient:

```
[x for x in regs if any(sub[1] == -1 for sub in x[-1])]
```

The `any()` test loops over the generator expression until a `True` value is found, at which point it stops iterating and returns `True`. This means that `x` is only included if there is a sublist in `x[-1]` whose second element is equal to `-1`.

Comment: Hmm. I only got [] as output for putting in your code. :/
Might that say anything about my list?

Comment: @HaikalYeo: your lists have further nesting, complicating matters. Are your sure your data structure is correct?

Comment: This is from the output of a previous function. If you are asking whether the representation of my data is correct, yes it is. The elements in my list are of the form: [['label', integer], integer, integer, [[integer, integer], [integer, integer], ...]].
My question was on the possibility that I may confused string with representation which I honestly don't know how to tell apart here.

Comment: @HaikalYeo: then searching should be limited to the last element of each sublist; adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for the one-liner. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

This should work with arbitrary nested lists:

```
def has_items(m):
    for x in m:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            if not isinstance(x[0], list):
                if len(x) == 2 and x[1] == -1: return x
            elif has_items(x): return x
    return False


print has_items(reversed(m))
```

Comment: You beat me to it, and your version is way cleaner than the solution I had. Upvoted.